# How to correctly use node.js child_process.spawn() redirection on Windows?

Tags: node.js

I have a clean Windows 8.1 box with lates node.js installed (v0.10.29). I have a following test code in two files:

**a.js**

```
var sub = require('child_process').spawn('node', ['b.js'], {silent: true});
sub.stdout.on("data", function (data) {console.log(data.toString());});
```

**b.js**

```
console.log("DEBUG 1");
console.log("DEBUG 2");
process.exit();
```

if i execute `a.ja` via:

```
node a.js
```

I will see "DEBUG 1" in console output - but not "DEBUG 2". If i remove `process.exit()`, both lines will be displayed correctly. This strange behavior happens both with `fork` and `spawn`.

Any hints? Same code works without problems on linux.

**Update 02.07.2014**

Seems this is not a race condition between exit() and log() since changing this to pure sequence produce same error:

```
function print(text, next) { console.log(text); next(); }
print("DEBUG 1", function () {
  print("DEBUG 2", function () {
    process.exit();
  });
});
```

**Update 03.07.2014**

`silent` is not listed in `spawn()` documentation, but it works. It is listed in `fork` documentation, and as I previously mentioned this problem is same with `fork`.

It seems that if I introduce a delay between last output and `process.exit()` all works correctly:

```
console.log("DEBUG 1");
console.log("DEBUG 2");
setTimeout(function () {process.exit();}, 10000);
```

But the problem manifest itself only if i **pipe** output to parent process: if I remove `silent`, both messages are displayed correctly even without delay, so it's most probably something wrong with pipe communication, not with `process.exit`.

**More updates 03.07.2014**

It was speculated in comments that `process.exit()` may terminate both processes (both `a.ja` and `b.ja`). No, it terminate only spawned/forked process, i checked this by adding infinite `setTimeout` to `a.js`, it happily works after `b.ja` is terminated, and still no "DEBUG 2" line.

Comment: I think that s because node.js is asynchronous, and process.exit is executed before console.log end. What if you try in a callback? `function print(text, callback) {console.log(text); callback();} print("DEBUG1", function () {print("DEBUG2", function () {process.exit();})});`

Comment: @DrakaSAN Updated question, same problem.

Comment: Also, silent option isn t referenced in spawn documentation.

Comment: @DrakaSAN Thanks for pointing that out. Updated question about spawn and fork

Comment: is there anything else to answer since my last edit? So I can rewrite my answer to make it clearer?

Comment: @DrakaSAN Thanks for narrowing problem to 'process.exit()'. I'm very interested WHY such behaviour with process exit + pipe (since without pipes all works fine), but if no one writes explanation i will accept your answer, thanks!

Comment: I ve edited and add a explaination of what I think is the problem is between `process.exit` and pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Major edit for clarity:

The problem you face is the concurrent event between `console.log('DEBUG2')` and `process.end()`, the two of them are called (almost) at the same time, but `process.end()` have a higher priority, and when done, make `sub` stop listen to event, and so stop DEBUG2 to be printed:

In your code:

```
a.js                |b.js
start
spawn               |start
listen              |send('DEBUG1')
get DEBUG1          |send('DEBUG2')
start the event     |send KILL
print DEBUG1        |
get DEBUG2
start the event
get KILL
kill b.js //DEBUG2 haven t been printed
```

Now, if you slow down process.end:

b.js:

```
console.log('DEBUG1');
console.log('DEBUG2');
setTimeout(function () {
    process.end();
}, 1000);

a.js                |b.js
start
spawn               |start
listen              |send('DEBUG1')
get DEBUG1          |send('DEBUG2')
start the event     |wait
print DEBUG1        |wait
get DEBUG2          |send KILL
start the event
print DEBUG2
get KILL
kill b.js
```

But that's bothersome, and you can t know how many "wait" there will be. Another solution is to make b.js inherit of stdout, so there is no event to make:

a.js:

```
var sub = require('child_process').spawn('node', ['b.js'], {stdio:[process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr]});

a.js                |b.js
start
spawn               |start
listen              |print DEBUG1
                    |print DEBUG2
                    |send KILL
get KILL            |
kill b.js
```

Now, no bug-prone code, but you can t get what is printed in a.js. I think another solution with process.nextTick could work, but I don t know how it would work.

EDIT:

`process.exit()` kill b.js, which is the intended behavior. a.js see the `data` event end, and so have a empty event loop, and so kill itself : )

Comment: Updated question, thanks for research. I will accept your answer if no one will explain what's the problem with pipe and process.exit()

Comment: Added some explaination on the problem.

Comment: This is not possible for process.exit() to end all the program. "spawn" and "fork" start separate process. Problem remains even if i put and endless loop in a.js (it never ends). So "process.exit()" actually ends only b.js :(. Updated question.

Comment: By listening to sub.end, I see that you re as right as me. process.exit only kill b.js, but somehow cancel the data event...