# Redirect stdout/stderr from a child_process to /dev/null or something similar

Tags: node.js, stdout, stderr, child-process

I am creating some child_processes with Node.js (`require('child_process')`) and I want to ensure that the stdout/stderr from each child_process does not go to the terminal, because I want only the output from the parent process to get logged. Is there a way to redirect the stdout/stderr streams in the child_processes to `/dev/null` or some other place that is not the terminal?

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

perhaps it's just:

```
var n = cp.fork('child.js',[],{
   stdio: ['ignore','ignore','ignore']
});
```

I just tried that, and that didn't seem to work.

Now I tried this:

```
var stdout, stderr;

if (os.platform() === 'win32') {
    stdout = fs.openSync('NUL', 'a');
    stderr = fs.openSync('NUL', 'a');
}
else {
    stdout = fs.openSync('/dev/null', 'a');
    stderr = fs.openSync('/dev/null', 'a');
}
```

and then this option:

```
stdio: ['ignore',  stdout, stderr],
```

but that didn't do it, but it seems like using the "detached:true" option might make this work.

Comment: how about just hijacking `process.stdout.write` in your forked process?

Comment: I can't unfortunately overwrite that, there must be a way with child_process to do this!

Comment: I suppose I could overwrite that actually, but there are advantages to doing this via the child_process call

Comment: In the docs it looks like the `stdio` option is for `spawn`, not `fork`, maybe you want the `silent` option?

Comment: @mzulch i think that the silent option might be the one

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/q/24484466/319204

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Solution:

To throw away the `stdout` and `stderr` of a forked childprocess:

1. setup a `pipe` i.e. use `silent = True` when forking.
2. And redirect the `stdout` and `stderr` pipes on the parent process into `/dev/null`.

---

### Explanation:

The [**node.js documentation** states](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) :

For convenience, `options.stdio` may be one of the following strings:

```
'pipe' - equivalent to ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe'] (the default)
'ignore' - equivalent to ['ignore', 'ignore', 'ignore']
'inherit' - equivalent to [process.stdin, process.stdout, process.stderr] or [0,1,2]
```

Apparently **[`childprocess.fork()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_fork_modulepath_args_options)** does NOT support `ignore`; Only [`childprocess.spawn()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) does.

> **`fork` does support a `silent` option that allows one to choose between `pipe` OR `inherit`.**

When forking a child process:
If `silent` = True, then stdio = `pipe`.
If `silent` = False, then stdio = `inherit`.

> `silent`
>   <sub>**Boolean**</sub>
>
> If true, stdin, stdout, and stderr of the child will be piped to the parent, otherwise they will be inherited from the parent.
>
> See the 'pipe' and 'inherit' options for child_process.spawn()'s stdio for more details.

Comment: thanks this answer is good, I upvoted awhile ago...I am currently wondering if there is a way to pipe the stderr/stdout of a child_process directly to a file instead of back to the parent process and then to the file. Any idea?

Comment: I guess just call process.stderr.pipe() in the child_process